# Replacement for windows SMTP server that supports DKIM signing

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, ssl, smtp, dkim

Can you recommend a SMTP server/component to replace the SMTP service that is available in Windows Server 2008.

I would like the SMTP server to support the same feature set as the built in SMTP service as well as:

Signing emails using Domain Keys/DKIM

SSL authentication (optional)

I'm using the SMTP server to send email from an ASP.Net web application. All emails will be sent from the same email address. I've got the PTR record and SFP records setup and would like to sign the emails to give some form of email authentication. I'm currently only connecting on localhost so SSl isn't required but this may change in the future.

If recommending a .Net component would I still need to relay through the Win2008 SMTP service or would this strip the signing headers?

Comment: What server did you end up using?

Answer (score 2):

I use and recommend http://www.emailarchitect.net/domainkeys/.

This creates an SMTP sink that signs all outgoing mail messages, while still using the SMTP server from IIS.

Comment: We ended up using this component also.

Comment: This isn't the only solution, see https://interactivethoughts.com/products/thinkdkim/.